# Returning variable once it reaches a number JS for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

What's the error in this function? I want to return the value of bk once it reaches 10, but the result is undefined?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = 0;
    var y = 50;
    var width = 10;
    var height = 10;
    function animate() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        x++;
        if(x <= 490) {
            setTimeout(animate, 33);
        }
    }
    animate();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400"
    style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have `bk < 10` as the condition. Once `bk` reaches 10, the condition will fail, and the iterations will stop, so it will not be returned.

Comment: `return` is not a function ... `return bk;` is much clearer ...

Comment: btw, what sense does it make to loop until a value and to check the (kind of) last value inside the loop. you could move the return statement after the loop instead of checking it *n* times in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your loop will never reach 10. Since you specified the condition
 `bk < 10`
Change the condition to `bk <= 10`. And then everything will work

```js
function doMyLoop () {
  for (var bk = 0; bk <= 10; bk++) {
    if (bk == 10) {
        return(bk); 
    } 
  }
}
console.log(doMyLoop ());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the return statement outside of the loop, bevause the last value of `bk` is `10`. The check with this value inside of the loop is never `true`.

```js
function doMyLoop () {
    for (var bk = 0; bk < 10; bk++) {
        console.log('insode loop', bk);
    }
    return bk; // 10
}

console.log(doMyLoop());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```